# Bootstrap 3 drop downmenu text color on mobile affect both small and large screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble about changing text color on mobile screen drop downmenu, specifically the text. The problem is if I changed the text color it will affect both the small screen and the large screen.

You can refer to this site http://bobbygerez.0fees.net/ and change it to small screen. The blog menu will give a dropdown but the color isn't good. As you can see on the large screen it looks fine but it also affect the small screen. I want to change only the text color for the small screen.

I used this code for the large screen. Please help, thanks.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
color: #5A5B5C;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply place the styling in the `max-width:767px` media query:

```
@media(max-width:767px){
    .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #FFF;
    }
}
```

The above styling will change the color of the submenu elements to white on smaller screens.

---

As a side note, it's worth mentioning that these are the media queries Bootstrap uses:

```
@media(max-width:767px){}
@media(min-width:768px){}
@media(min-width:992px){}
@media(min-width:1200px){}
```